# Save chat between two user in openfire server in android xmpp

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

![enter image description here][1]

It is possible to save chat history in openfire server. I have configure an Openfire 3.9.3 and connect mysql database. In mysql database provide a lots of table but in these table we can not find out any chat message table to save my chat between a two users.If any developers know how to save chat message and get a chat message in openfire using xmmp. Please help me as soon as possible.

//Sorry i can not post a image of openfire and mysql db because of reputation is below 10.

```
// Set a listener to send a chat text message
    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String to = mRecipient.getText().toString();
            String text = mSendText.getText().toString();
            if(!text.equals("")){
                if(connection!=null){

                    Message msg = new Message(to+"@172.167.41.165", Message.Type.chat);
                    msg.setBody(text);
                    connection.sendPacket(msg);
                    messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
                    messages.add(text);
                    setListAdapter();
                    mSendText.setText("");
                }

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(XMPPClient.this, "Please Fill Input Field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use openfire Monitoring plugin for this

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/monitoring/readme.html